# PL/SQL: on update attempt, delete row which causes unique_violation exception

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception, sql-delete

I am trying to update a table in the following way, and getting a unique_violation exception which is expected

```
my.db=# UPDATE my_table SET code = REPLACE(code, ‘abd’, ‘abc’);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (code, group_id)=(abc, 1) already exists.
```

I know that I need to delete the incorrect row instead of updating it if it causes this exception so I'm trying to write something like the following

```
DO $$ 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE my_table SET code = REPLACE(code, ‘abd’, ‘abc’);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN unique_violation THEN
            DELETE FROM my_table WHERE code = ‘abd’ AND group_id = ?;
END $$;
```

How would I delete only the row causing the exception to be thrown and make sure my updates continue to run on all other entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it in a `BEGIN..END` block within an implicit cursor for loop.

```
DO $$ 
    BEGIN
    for rec IN ( select code, group_id FROM my_table ) 
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        UPDATE my_table SET code = REPLACE(code, 'abd', 'abc') WHERE code=rec.code AND group_id=rec.group_id;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN unique_violation THEN
            DELETE FROM my_table WHERE code = 'abd' AND group_id = ?;
      END;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! So in the delete statement I can just use `group_id = rec.group_id` now. Thanks for your help